StringJoin fails in .m
Do[(
  ND$T$thr[j] = j;
  ND$T$thr[j] >> "test_" <> ToString[j] <> ".dat";
  ), {j, 1, 3}]

This works without issue in a notebook and creates 3 files with different file names and different content. However, in a .m file that I run on ubuntu in the terminal with math -script test.m &  this fails,   with the error
StringJoin::string: String expected at postion 1 in Null<>1.dat.

Any ideas why and how to fix this?
Thanks!

I found a working solution: Put[table[j], "test_" <> ToString[j] <> ".dat"]; instead of >> works, but I would love to know why this fails. It makes no sense to me.

Can't check at the moment, but I'm pretty sure >> is one of these magic operators that don't work on .m files (similar to ? or << if I'm not mistaken)

yes that seems to be the case. Is this a bug or is there a legit reason for this? I always test my scripts locally as a .nb before I upload them to the cluster and it is pretty annoying to waste a lot of CPU hours because saving the file failed

It's not the problem in StringJoin, but in Put. I believe this is related to what is mentioned in the documentation for Put under Possible Issues, namely that:

The form expr>>filename treats filename as a literal name, not an expression to be evaluated.

The provided solution is to use Put[expr, filename].
You can simulate the same behaviour also in a notebook by trying to parse the same command via ToExpression:
j = 1;

a >> "test_" <> ToString[1] <> ".dat"
(* Works as expected. *)

ToExpression["a >> \"test\"<>ToString[1]<>\".dat\""]
(* StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1 in Null<>1.dat. *)


I'll accept this as the solution since it solves the problem. I still think stuff that works in a .nb should work in a .m and I would like to understand why this fails, but it might just be a bug and I have to remember to use Put in .m files. Thanks!
